# Display data from mysql in JTable

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

How can I inster my data from mysql table into my JTable? And I would like to be able to make UPDATE,DELETE and ADD operation into mysql table.
This should my a restaurant application and I want the user to see in that JTable the restaurant stock and clicking the table button it opens a new frame where the user can add or delete or cash in products from the stock to that table. It would be cool that mysql table to auto update once a product is added or deleted from the table consumation.

```
package project_bar;


import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;


public class MainMenu extends javax.swing.JFrame {
Connection conn = new DBConnection().connect();
PreparedStatement pst = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
    public MainMenu() {
        initComponents();

    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        logout_bt = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        table1_bt = new javax.swing.JButton();
        table1_lb = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        table2_lb = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        table2_bt = new javax.swing.JButton();
        table3_lb = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        table3_bt = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Bauturi_lb = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        Table_stock = new javax.swing.JTable();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        logout_bt.setText("LOGOUT");
        logout_bt.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                logout_btActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Verdana", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Tamas Vlad Restaurant");

        table1_bt.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));
        table1_bt.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/round_table-128.png"))); // NOI18N
        table1_bt.setText("TABLE 1");
        table1_bt.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                table1_btActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        table1_lb.setText("TABLE 1");

        table2_lb.setText("Table 2");

        table2_bt.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));
        table2_bt.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/round_table-128.png"))); // NOI18N
        table2_bt.setText("TABLE 1");
        table2_bt.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                table2_btActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        table3_lb.setText("Table 3");

        table3_bt.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));
        table3_bt.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/round_table-128.png"))); // NOI18N
        table3_bt.setText("TABLE 1");
        table3_bt.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                table3_btActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Bauturi_lb.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Vani", 3, 24)); // NOI18N
        Bauturi_lb.setText("DRINKS ON STOCK");

        Table_stock.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Name", "Quantity", "Price"
            }
        ) {
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                false, false, false
            };

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        Table_stock.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        Table_stock.addAncestorListener(new javax.swing.event.AncestorListener() {
            public void ancestorMoved(javax.swing.event.AncestorEvent evt) {
            }
            public void ancestorAdded(javax.swing.event.AncestorEvent evt) {
                Table_stockAncestorAdded(evt);
            }
            public void ancestorRemoved(javax.swing.event.AncestorEvent evt) {
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(Table_stock);
        Table_stock.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(logout_bt)
                .addGap(334, 334, 334)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 243, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 599, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(41, 41, 41)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(Bauturi_lb, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 262, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGap(138, 138, 138)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(table1_bt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 84, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(table1_lb, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 84, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(123, 123, 123)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(table2_bt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 84, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(table2_lb, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 47, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(135, 135, 135)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(table3_lb)
                    .addComponent(table3_bt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 84, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(logout_bt))
                .addGap(68, 68, 68)
                .addComponent(Bauturi_lb, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 124, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(table1_lb)
                            .addComponent(table2_lb)
                            .addComponent(table3_lb))
                        .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(table1_bt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 54, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(table2_bt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 54, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(table3_bt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 54, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(38, 38, 38)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addGap(556, 556, 556))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(19, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void table1_btActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
         new Table1().show();

    }                                         

    private void logout_btActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        this.dispose();
             new Login(null,true).show();

    }                                         

    private void table2_btActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
         new Table1().show();
    }                                         

    private void table3_btActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
         new Table1().show();

    }                                         

    private void Table_stockAncestorAdded(javax.swing.event.AncestorEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:

    }                                         



    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MainMenu().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel Bauturi_lb;
    private javax.swing.JTable Table_stock;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JButton logout_bt;
    private javax.swing.JButton table1_bt;
    private javax.swing.JLabel table1_lb;
    private javax.swing.JButton table2_bt;
    private javax.swing.JLabel table2_lb;
    private javax.swing.JButton table3_bt;
    private javax.swing.JLabel table3_lb;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Execute SQL query, pull the row information from the database `ResultSet`, wrap the data in a POJO and add it to the table model.  It's usually better to use a custom `TableModel` based on `AbstractTableModel` (IMHO) as it gives you more control over how the data is managed. See [JDBC Database Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) and [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

Comment: I accomplished the same with what @MadProgrammer mentioned, with a few tweaks to fit my needs. Why do you want to use an auto-update in such an instance? It's not like the kitchen is going to start making a burger and then dispose the burger to create a pizza. Your network bandwidth will also degrade the more queries you have to handle, esp autoupdate

Comment: the auto update is just for the stock part.. so if you have no more coke left an alert messaje will pop

Answer (score 1):

```
    DbConnection conn = new DbConnection();
    Connection connection = conn.getConnection();
    Statement st;
    Vector data = new Vector();
    try {
        st = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT col_name FROM table_name");
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = res.getMetaData();
        int columns = metaData.getColumnCount();
        while (res.next()) {
           Vector row = new Vector(columns);
           for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
            row.addElement(res.getObject(i));
           }
           data.addElement(row);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Vector columnNames = new Vector();
    columnNames.addElement("col_1");
    columnNames.addElement("col_name_n");
    table = new JTable(data,columnNames);
```

You can use something like that the code above. 
Steps:
1.You make the connection with database
2.You execute the query
3.Store the data from database into a vector
4.Create Jtable with the data that are stored in the vectors

Comment: You're not closing your resources, leaving your connection and other associated resources open, which could affect the performance of the database. There is no need to create a new `JTable` each time you make a query, simply either create or update the existing model. This example is going to come back and haunt us.